# Javascript to check first letter of a string is capital

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I am trying to create javascript function which checks that only first letter of the string is capital, spaces allowed and no numbers in the string.
I want to do it with regular expression.
Problem is how can i check if only first letter is capital and others are lower case. 
Here is my code:

```
function upper_case(str)
{
   regexp = /^[A-Z]/;
   if (regexp.test(str))
    {
      console.log("String's first character is uppercase");
    } 
    else
    {
      console.log("String's first character is not uppercase");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `/^[A-Z][^A-Z]+$/`

Comment: `/^[A-Z][a-z\s]*$`

Comment: @Mohammad _"...and no numbers in the string"_

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs So `/^[A-Z][^A-Z0-9]+$/`

Comment: @Mohammad: This is matching `A;,%*µ...`

Answer (score -1):

You can create a function that checks the ASCII value of character at first position.

```
function checkFirstUpperCase(str) {
    if(str.charCodeAt(0) >= 65 && str.charCodeAt(0) <= 91) { 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This should do the job.

Comment: OP Explicitly asks for a regular expression and has more requirements then only the first character. "_spaces allowed and no numbers in the string_" and "_check if only first letter is capital and others are lower case_". Unfortunately they haven't disclosed every rule (like what about punctuation marks?) which makes this impossible to answer.